# Multiple result display MongoDB Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was writing code for crypto currency rates display backend,

I have 2 main problems are

**First:**

```
    last: {
    rate: (idx, cb) => {
        models.master.find({}).where('id',idx).limit(10).exec((err,data)=>{
            if(data && data.length>0)   cb(data);
            else cb(err);
        });
    }
}
```

have a look at the code it always having only one data JSON object instead it should have multiple instead.

**Second:**

How can I sort by recently added data means I already added time key in order to do so but I am with the lack of knowledge.(both ascending and descending)

```
"time":"5-7-2017_12:05:43:PM"
```

**Test MongoDB object:**

```
[{"_id":"595c88bf4d451b206454434b","time":"5-7-2017_12:05:43:PM","id":"bitcoin","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","rank":"1","price_usd":"2561.25","price_btc":"1.0","market_cap_usd":"42078648188.0","available_supply":"16428950.0","total_supply":"16428950.0","percent_change_1h":"0.2","percent_change_24h":"-2.42","percent_change_7d":"2.13","last_updated":"1499236459","price_inr":"165829.411875","market_cap_inr":"2724403116224","__v":0}]
```

Comment: Usually, If you search `where('id',idx)` you looking for 1 item, maybe you making a wrong request?

Comment: @O.Borcuhin whats right thing please mention.

Comment: To compare dates you need to use timestamp like in `last_updated` field or save time as a JS Date `new Date(time)`. But for me, better use timestamp. Then in `find()` method, you can use orderBy operator with `-1` or `1` value.
More information you can find here: 
`https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/`

Comment: The problem here is that `"time"` data contains a "string", and one that is not even subject to a "lexical" sort as `"2017-07-05T12:05:43.000Z"` would be. So you need to convert the data in order to "sort", or indeed "search by range". But since you need to do that anyway then you should convert to BSON `Date` instead, since it takes less space than a string, and as a value with underlying numeric properties of the timestamp, it is far more useful. You should therefore update all your data and parse the "strings" to `Date` objects instead. Then you can get your desired results.

Comment: Also "this is not JSON". You need to get that thought out of your head. MongoDB "internally" stores data as BSON. But from the point of view of your code it's just "native data structures", in this case plain JavaScript Objects and arrays.

Comment: what about FIRST problem for multiple result display